# EC2 t1.micro - can I run one mongodb with a node server normally?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I intend to use ec2 of amazon web services for building a personal site written by angularJS on nodejs server with NoSQL mongodb(just information and blog) and few tests, study deployment on linux server.

So that someone please give me some suggestions about aws services (include plans, instance run-type ( on-demand, reserves or spot), storage, IOs, bandwidth if it has).

The low cost is need but must not be lowest, I just want it runs normally without any server side's issue.

Thanks all.

Comment: It will *greatly* vary on your usage. For a personal site, I would suggest you deploy in micro and see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be fine if you don't have much load/users. I was running apache + tomcat + mongo on a micro instance (~ 600Mb RAM) and it was ok. It is free for 1 year from the time you register. You can easily change instance type without reinstall later if you feel its running out of resources. You can find pricing details and calculator on AWS site, but micro instance is around $10 per month, and small is about $24 or a bit more.

Comment: I'm using free tier, I could help me predict my usage. with small it does not require about EBS and provide a hard disk (160GB). So... is it better using micro + EBS or small?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can , currently i am using the micro instance of apache + mongo and it works fine . The only issue i saw when i was using the micro instance of the windows server + mongo . It was too slow because of the this reason i moved to Ubuntu and mongoDB + php which is working cool

Comment: thanks for your information. Now my last question is about hard disk : should I use micro with EBS or small with 160GB HDD? I read a compare document between micro vs small. It's about CPU : sometime micro has CPU max freq higher than small. The IO EBS was said very low and small is low. hm.... could you please give me more information?